# Порядковый номер атрибута класса

Tags: python, классы

Добрый вечер.
Есть класс (mongoengine):

```
class BaseMetaDocument(Document): 
    unit = StringField()
    name = StringField()
    active = BooleanField()
```

Как получить, что порядковый номер unit=1, name=2, active=3?
Сейчас я просто добавил свойство order=1,2,3 и т.д. для каждого поля, может есть какой то более простой способ?

Comment: В общем случае такое невозможно, в конкретном этом случае зависит от класса Document

Comment: Ок, спасибо, попробую код глянуть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это невозможно (можно создать вспомогательный индекс - см. обновление ниже). Все аттрибуты хранятся в поле `__dict__`. Это словарь, а словарь не гарантирует сохранения порядка элементов. Например:

```
class CL:
    bar = "a"
    boo = "b"
    spam = "c"

print(CL.__dict__)
```

Результат: `{'__module__': '__main__', 'spam': 'c', 'bar': 'a', '__doc__': None, 'boo': 'b'}`

Как видно, порядок совсем другой. В качестве запасного выхода можно добавить аттрибут `index = ["bar", "boo", "spam"]` и получать значения примерно так: `getattr(CL(), CL.index[0])`

---

**Обновление с метаклассами**:
Согласно [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) - возможно сохранить порядок полей на этапе создания класса. Тело класса обрабатывается как обычный код, но словарь, в котором хранятся локальные переменные, заменяется на нашу структуру. Например, OrderedDict, чтобы запомнить порядок. Такой подход не избавляет от специального аттрибута с индексом, но так нет необходимости заполнять его вручную и следить за тем, чтобы ничего не забыть туда добавить. Делается это таким образом:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class Meta(type) :
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
        print("META for {name} prepare".format(name=name))
        return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(self, name, bases, __dict__):
        # Мы не продолжаем использовать OrderedDict(), класс все равно создается со словарем
        __dict__['index'] = [key for key in __dict__ if key not in ('__module__', '__qualname__')]
        return type.__new__(self, name, bases, __dict__)


class MyClass(metaclass=Meta):
    bar = "a"
    foo = "yo!"

    def method(self):
        pass

    baz = 123
    spam = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


print(MyClass.index)
```

Вывод: `['bar', 'foo', 'method', 'baz', 'spam']`

Comment: для людей, который прекращают читать после полного предложения: *"Это невозможно."* укажите что они могут использовать `OrderedDict`(достаточно фразы: "см. обновление внизу" ).